# Typescript error TS2322 applying className to @material-ui/core Box

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Getting typescript error applying a className to a Box element; odd thing the same source works on other devs' boxes with an almost identical config.

Using:
"@material-ui/core": "4.11.3",
"typescript": "4.1.5"

tsc --version
Version 4.1.5

```
/src/components/NoSearchResultsOverlay/NoSearchResultsOverlay.tsx
TypeScript error in .../client-app/src/components/NoSearchResultsOverlay/NoSearchResultsOverlay.tsx(18,21):
Type '{ children: Element; marginY: number; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & BoxProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.      
  Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & BoxProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.  TS2322
```

```
import React from "react";
import {
    Box,
    Grid,
    Typography
} from "@material-ui/core";
import NoSearchResultsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FindInPage";

import useStyles from "./styles";

type NoSearchResultsOverlayProps = {
    show: boolean;
}

const NoSearchResultsOverlay = ({ show = false }: NoSearchResultsOverlayProps) => {
    const classes = useStyles({ show });
    return (
        <Box marginY={15} className={classes.container}>
```

Answer (score 0):

classes.container value need to be checked which is returned from useStyles hooks.
It is suppose to be string, might be receiving some different type.